# How can I link SQL query Data with javaScript in HTML at Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, html

I want pass SQL data(employee_id) with javaScript function in html button in Oracle APEX.
when I click the Html button it will pass the SQL value to another item.

```
select SUB_MENU_ID,SUB_MENU_NAME into V_SUB_MENU_ID,V_SUB_MENU_NAME from  DPMTS_SUB_MENU
 where SUB_MENU_ID = x.SUB_MENU_ID
 Htp.p('<li class= "demo">     
           <a href="f?p=104:2:&SESSION.::&DEBUG.::P2_ID: &V_SUB_MENU_ID" 
          </li>'||x.SUB_MENU_NAME||'
           <!-- <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Pro</span> -->
                  </a>
                </li> '); 
                end loop;
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I cannot link my value with this url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know who is x? one onpen li and 2 close /li and why you have the end loop?
but you need to change 
this

```
 Htp.p('<li class= "demo">     
       <a href="f?p=104:2:&SESSION.::&DEBUG.::P2_ID: &V_SUB_MENU_ID" 
      </li>'||x.SUB_MENU_NAME||'
       <!-- <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success">Pro</span> -->
              </a>
            </li> ');
```

with

```
 Htp.p('<li class= "demo">     
          <a href="f?p=104:2:&SESSION.::&DEBUG.::P2_ID:'||V_SUB_MENU_ID || '"> '||V_SUB_MENU_NAME || ' </a>   
       </li>');
```

your &V_SUB_MENU_ID is seen as a string which is not good.